# how to create a flash message when a user successfully logged in on fortify?

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-fortify

how to create a flash message when a user successfully logged in on fortify?
later in the blade view I just need to call using

```
            @if(session()->has('success-login'))
                <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ session()->get('success-login') }}</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects) you can use the `with` method and redirect to your custom page with a flash message.

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->instance(LoginResponse::class, new class implements LoginResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            return redirect('/')->with('success-login', 'message');
        }
    });
}
```